# Advice to implement cache solution for a site

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching

I'm working on a public site that soon will not longer be 100% public. Paid users will be able to access 100% of the features while "anonymous" users will access a reduced version.

The problem is that anonymous users and paid users will access the same pages, but they'll see different things.

I wonder about how to keep using cache for all pages. I have to 100% sure that I show the correct content for each type of user. Will be extremely bad to show a cached version of the paid site to an anonymous user (and the other way around).

Preferably, without adding anything to the url to differentiate user type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the application cache for your business data, which is basically a dictionary of key value pairs, which you can put anything you like into. Then you can programatically check if they're logged in. You'll still be rendering the page on each visit, but hopefully retrieving the cached data will provide the required performance boost.

Alternatively, it might be [possible to turn off the output-cache programatically, as described in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043112/programatically-control-output-caching-disable-or-enable-cache-according-to-par)

Quote [this answer from David Ebbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043112/programatically-control-output-caching-disable-or-enable-cache-according-to-par/1984362#1984362):

In OnInit:

```
if (yourArbitraryCondition) {
    OutputCacheParameters outputCacheSettings = new OutputCacheParameters();
    outputCacheSettings.Duration = 60;
    InitOutputCache(outputCacheSettings);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your help. "Application Cache" (or cache object) is a must and we'll use it but we need to handle eventual peaks on the public site with "HTTP Cache" settings so the web server farm don't get killed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for would be accomplished by the **varybycustom** option for output caching.  Using this you define a function to return a custom parameter value that is used when retrieving the output cached version of a page so that users will get their own personalized cached version, and all anonymous users should see the same cached version since they will be using some the same value.  Here is a link with more information:
http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/10/29/VaryByCustom-Caching-By-User.aspx

For programmatic data caching you should use the user id as part of they key to retrieve the data to achieve the same effect.